# iOS PDF Annotation (notes, comments)

Tags: ios, pdf, annotations

I am working on PDF based application for iPad. I'm adding a feature to supports reading annotations (Notes/Comments). I have searched lot on the net, but I didnt find any relevant info. and I'm using Quartz.

I can get PDF page info using :

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef CGPDFPageGetDictionary ( CGPDFPageRef page );
```

And using "Annots" key `bool CGPDFDictionaryGetArray ( CGPDFDictionaryRef dict, "Annots", CGPDFArrayRef *value );`

How to I can get annotation for particular page. If I am right what is key for Notes?

If i am wrong at all in above concern please let me know how Notes gets rendered on PDF. Or where PDF renderer gets info about Notes.?

Please let me know If any one knows ASAP. 
If there is any articles talking about this subject please let me know.

Really thanks in advance.